# Magento 2 Add CAPTCHA to login form in createblock

Tags: magento2.4.1, widget, cms-pages

I am building a widget to allow the Login form to display on a CMS page. I am able to get the form to display, but when I try to login, I am redirected to the customer/account page and get the error "invalid Captcha". Captcha is turned on and works just fine on the customer/account page.

/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Widget/Login.php

```
    namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Widget;

    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
    use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;

    class Login extends Template implements BlockInterface
    {
        protected $_template = "widget/login.phtml";
    }
```

/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/widget/login.phtml

```
   <?php

    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login")->setTemplate("Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml")->toHtml();
```

Form on CMS Page:

[image: Form on CMS Page]

Form on customer/account:
[image: customer/account]

Answer (score 0):

Anyone?
I also need an answer on this.
Trying the same with the registration-page: problem is, that the captcha is not loaded when called via createBlock.

How to fix this?

EDIT:
I found the solution finally after days.
It must be exakt this code, to insert also the reCaptcha as a block, here i.e. für the register-page:

```
echo $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('MSP\ReCaptcha\Block\Frontend\ReCaptcha',
    'msp-recaptcha',
    ['data' =>
        [
            'jsLayout' =>
                [
                    'components' =>
                        [
                            'msp-recaptcha' =>
                                [
                                    'component' => 'MSP_ReCaptcha/js/reCaptcha',
                                    'reCaptchaId' => 'msp-recaptcha',
                                    'zone' => 'create'
                                ]
                        ]
                ]
        ]
    ]
)
->setTemplate('MSP_ReCaptcha::msp_recaptcha.phtml')
->toHtml();
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/204506)

Comment: What are you talking about? I didnt ANSWERED the question, NOBODY does. So i just added some input for another, but same, case, so someone maybe knows the answer!

Comment: did you tried directly use of captcha in form with jquery?